# Different diagnostics.wadcfg file for each publish profile

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-web-roles, azure-diagnostics

As far as I know, regarding *web-roles*, it is possible to have multiple **ServiceConfiguration.cscfg** files, one for each publish profile (for example, *Cloud1,* *Cloud2,* *Cloud3,* *Local* and so on).

Though, is it possible to have different **diagnostics.wadcfg** *(wadcfgx)* files?

How to instruct Visual Studio to use a specific *diagnostics* file when deploying to Azure? Is there a specific entry in the *publish profile* XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, it is not possible because there can be only one diagnostics.wadcfg (wadcfgx) file associated with a role in a cloud project <del>a cloud project</del>.

We are using SDK 2.4 in our project and the way we have worked around this problem is by creating separate cloud projects for each environment - Dev, Staging, and Production. Since these are separate cloud projects, we can have different diagnostics configurations.

If you're using SDK 2.5, one thing that works in your favor is the diagnostics is now an extension (instead of plugin). What that allows you to do is change/enable/disable diagnostics on the fly. Though I have not tried it but one thing you could possibly do is enable diagnostics as a part of your deployment process. By default there won't be any diagnostics.wadcfgx file in your project. When you deploy your code via PowerShell, after successful deployment, you can enable this extension. Please see Step 4 here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics/#worker-role. (Since I have not tried it myself, I would be very much interested in knowing the outcome. Please do share if this approach worked for you).

Comment: Thanks :) I'll let you know if I apply this solution.